# Having some issues with html events, ajax, and getting the correct value into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i'm trying to wrap my head around html events, the use of ajax, and javascript

lets say i have a drop down box with countries

```
    countries: <select name='country' id='country' onchange='showhotel(this.value);showpictures(this.value);'>
               <option value='country1'>country1</option>
               <option value='country2'>country2</option>
               </select>
```

and i use ajax to output hotels in selected country in a new dropbox, but i also have function that would output pictures of the hotels under the form

```
    Hotels: <select name='hotel' id='hotel'></select>
    </form>
    <div id='picture'> </div>
```

now lets say I've selected a country and outputted a picture

```
   <div id='picture'> <img src='picture of hotel.jpg' onmouseover='showroom()'> </div>
```

now i want it so when i hover over a picture it will use the value from the hotels drop down box to output pictures of the room the hotel have available

now the question is

```
   onmouseover="showroom(what the hell do i put in here to make this work???)"
```

like i said i use ajax to make this work, and since the img line is outputted from php i tried what i though would be the obvious

```
    echo ("<img src='$pictureOfHotel' onmouseover='showroom($hotel)'>");
```

that didn't work, I've tried several thing for hours now, and i can't wrap my head around how to get this to work. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the hotel currently selected the one displayed in the picture?

Comment: What do you have in `showroom()`?

Comment: I suggest , instead of showing the images, please show the hotels name or use mouse click and show in popup. And in "showroom()" use the drop down element Id and get its value and pass in Ajax.

Comment: right now i have nothing in showroom, and I have a table that list all the pictures of the hotels in selected country